# Counting overlapping objects

Tags: grid, counting, fastest-algorithm, pattern-matching

Consider a NxN pixel grid with up to M objects drawn on it, either squares or diamonds:

[image: 3x3 grid of black squares ("squares")]square
   [image: 3x3 grid with black squares forming a plus symbol ("diamonds")]diamond

The objects may overlap, so recognition is hard. The task is to give the minimal possible **numbers of objects per shape** that can be "seen" in the picture and tell how many squares, how many diamonds, and how many objects with unknown shape there are.

You can find a reference algorithm that solves the problem [**here**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/34554/25362).

Here are some examples with their intended numbers (n<sub>square</sub>, n<sub>diamond</sub>, n<sub>unknown</sub>). The examples with n<sub>unknown</sub> = 1 are those with pixels that may either come from a square or a diamond (highlighted in black, but not bearing any information that may be used).

[image: s list of test cases containing 12 different grid configurations]

The program with shortest mean runtime in terms of grid size N wins!

And this is a simple test case generator:

```
let N = 10

// initialize the grid
let grid = Array.from(Array(N), () => new Array(N));

// choose a random number of objects <= M
let n = Math.ceil(Math.random()*M)

// create objects
while (n-- > 0) {

    // choose random position, but not on the border of the grid
    var i = Math.ceil((N-2)*Math.random())
    var j = Math.ceil((N-2)*Math.random())

    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        // draw a square
        for (var k = -1; k <=1; k++) {
            for (var l = -1; l <=1; l++) {
                grid[i+k][j+l] = 1
            }
        }
    } else {
        // draw a diamond
        for (var k = -1; k <=1; k++) {
            for (var l = -1; l <=1; l++) {
                if (!(k && l)) {
                    grid[i+k][j+l] = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some small test cases:

[image]

Comment: For a 3x9 rect, the middle 3x3 are all unknown? Promised it can be built with the two shapes?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I think this is going to require some clarification. E.g., in the `(2,0,1)` examples, why isn't it 3 or 5 squares? Since the very center pixel could be the center of a square centered around it, overlapping with the other two. And the two pixels on either side of it could also be the center of a square, unless they're not allowed to touch, which doesn 't seem to be specified in the question.

Comment: @l4m2: Promised!

Comment: @taRadvylfsriksushilani: It's not 3 squares (3,0,0) or 2 squares and 1 diamond (2,1,0) because it could be either of both. It's not 5 squares because 2 of them would be completely hidden and could not be "seen". Everything is allowed to touch or overlap.

Comment: What is \$f\left(\begin{matrix}*&*&*&{}&{}\\ *&*&*&b&{}\\ *&*&*&*&*\\ {}&a&*&*&*\\ {}&{}&*&*&*\end{matrix}\right)\$? The \$a\$ can be square or cross

Comment: @l4m2: Both must be crosses, the only entries in the table are crosses (representing 1s or so). The squares and diamonds are arrangments of such crosses, your table shows 3 overlapping squares made out of crosses (when you replaced a and b by crosses), i.e. corresponds to (3,0,0).

Comment: @l4m2: If a is cross and b is empty (0) we see 2 squares (overlapping in the center of the table) and 1 diamond (which can be at two positions, we don't know which), i.e. it corresponds to (2,1,0)

Comment: Why not (2,2,0)?

Comment: @l4m2: Good question. In this case I would say because it needs more objects (Occam's razor!). I should put this in  my question.

Comment: @l4m2: Or there should be place for ambiguity, so both possibilities should be given as result. Or any of it counts.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker [here](https://ibb.co/4fv5SfZ) is another ill-defined example. Personally I would just count the number of 1x1 squares instead of shapes.

Comment: @AnttiP: It would be interesting to see, if there are ambiguous examples with the same (minimal) number of objects. If not so, I would require that the number of objects must be minimal (then being a unique solution). (Otherwise, please see my last comments above.)

Comment: @AnttiP It only say `problem`

Comment: @l4m2 The red shape at the top left is an ambiguous shape. There are two possible constructions of the shape displayed at the bottom left and top right corner. You see the image, right?

Comment: @AnttiP: It doesn't really matter for my question, but do you manage to "see" the the (2,3,0) case instead of the (3,0,0) case? Can you let the mental picture jump (like for the Necker cube)? (Personally, I can only "see" the (3,0,0) case in the shape at the top left.)

Comment: @AnttiP I see no image

Comment: @l4m2 try this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGGhn.png

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker I can't "see" the (2,3,0) case either. But, yeah, if you add that the number of shapes is minimal to the challenge description, I think it's well-defined.

Comment: @l4m2: In any case you need 3 3x3 squares + 1 object to cover the 3x10 rectangle, so I guess it's (3,0,1) without ambiguity.

Comment: I think `n_unknown` covered ambiguity

Comment: @l4m2: So to say.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a testcase generator, so that scoring answers will be easier. Something that takes `N` as input and outputs a random `N*N` grid that satisfies the rules.

Comment: @AnttiP: Which language do you suggest?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Any popular open source language. For example Python, C, Javascript or Java. Just try to avoid MATLAB or the Wolfram language.

Comment: @AnttiP: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why isn't the (3,0,1) case instead listed as (4,0,0), with squares centered at each of the dark pixels in your "To show how the pictures where drawn" section?  [NB: You'll want to change where ->were.] If you assign the first three squares from the bottom up, you will be left with the top 2/3 of the fourth (top) square exposed; this can be assigned as the fourth square, since it's allowed that its bottom  row overlaps with the top row of the square below it.

Comment: @theorist: The fourth object, highlighted in black, can be either a square or a diamond, but you cannot tell. That's the essence. It **could** be a square (as in your "reconstruction" of the drawing), but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @RadvylfPrograms: I replaced my answer by a link in the question.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), O(2ⁿ)

```hs
import Data.Bits
import Data.List
listFromPair=uncurry((.pure).(:))
s`isSubsetOf`p=s.&.p==s
bsum=foldl(.|.)0::[Integer]->Integer
numbers n p=let
 w=[0..n-3]
 diamond=[1,n+0,n+1,n+2,2*n+1]
 square=diamond++[0,2,2*n,2*n+2]
 solutions=sortOn length$filter((p==).bsum)$subsequences$
   filter(`isSubsetOf`p)[bsum[bit(r*n+c+d)|d<-s]|r<-w,c<-w,s<-[diamond,square]]
 minlength=length$solutions!!0
 best=takeWhile((minlength==).length)solutions
 numb=map minimum.transpose$map(map length.listFromPair.partition((9==).popCount))best
 in numb++[minlength-sum numb]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFNaxsxEL3rVyiwFCneFes1pK2xcmhLoVBIoYccloVovXIsoq9oJELB/92V7I2THDQaZt7MezOzF/AktT4elfEuRPxDRMG@qQjofeC3goh0Nj@DM3@ECjzZbQrhHyHMpyApI2tKETwo@JtGkPFu9@A5sE/Mcw5ohGT4zulJE3ZgtF2v@182ykcZhuZ29pBNZpQBsMWeaxkRfuF9y5htVgPCkxLG2Yn3y9ou2vzK39XddfZyGp6TCJLPqMWib@tT8gToCsDpFJWzwCEPdWexlvYx7qud0lEGQrJMyopMWkEZ4DlJu5VQIYzxjPkwG@0LuB9VJCFTbBcTPUybBoZD2DQv9bYY2DT9rKg@CxyyEqPsmZvPEi7Srq5ahEcJkUfxJO/3SktC3uBZ4NmjlwqEy9K4Eb60VSYZFoOw4B3IKkdJyZyL2PvrMS9CVKUFIV9LY@/8d5dspLTwI6zsqXNe5IW/yfOegsPRCGW5D8rG6vVon/PaTKHEeSVVv7xhbPllyPVdx1h3U7xVPuaqG47/AQ)